# How to create thumbnail image for document(doc, html) loaded in UIWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, thumbnails

- In a `tableview` am listing following document files **jpg, png, html, txt, doc, xls**.
- I got thumbnail for image files like jpg, png jpeg, etc...
- In `didselect` method of `tableview` am navigate into another view controller to load these document files in `UIWebView`.
- Can anybody tell **how to create thumbnail image** of the document to add for cell image in `tableview`.

1.First `ViewController` in Tableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([FileType isEqualToString:@"jpg"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[FilelistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    }
    else if ([FileType isEqualToString:@"doc"])
    {
        cell.imageView.image = ??????
    }
}
```

2.Second `ViewController`..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FileName" ofType:@"doc"]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL]             
    WebView.delegate = self;
    [WebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    CGFloat contentHeight = WebView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    [WebView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:WebView];
}
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: You want an actual thumbnail that shows some of the content of the documents? or maybe just using a static image would be fine...

Comment: @MatíasR: Need actual thumbnail image only.

Comment: One thing you can do is load the document in a UIWebView and take a screenshot. Store it as an image an use it afterwards as a thumbnail. I'll post the code as an answer, it will be unreadable as a comment.

Comment: How did you manage to get the thumbnail for a pdf? I have pdfs stored in my server and want to display a thumbnail but haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can load the content in the UIWebView and capture it with:

```
- (UIImage*)screenshot:(UIView*)theView
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theView.bounds.size);
    [theView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Store the image returned and use it as a thumbnail.
You can generate it the first time the user views the document (in which case the first time the user sees the list the thumbnail won't be available) or generate them all in the view controller with the table view. For this second option, you'd have to create a UIWebView and put it out of the frame of the superview, where it's not visible, and then capture it.

Now that I'm thinking, maybe there's another option... simply use a small UIWebView instead of an image in the case the document is not an image, and load the document. It should appear small on the cell. Just make sure to set `scalesPageToFit` to YES.

**EDIT:**

I quickly tried my last suggestion and it worked. I created a UIViewController with a UITableView, a cell that has a UIWebView inside with tag 1000. Then I do:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"webViewTableCell"];

    UIWebView *wv = (UIWebView *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    wv.scalesPageToFit = NO;
    wv.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [wv loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://studentaid.ed.gov/sites/default/files/public-service-employment-certification-form.pdf"]]];

    return cell;
}
```

It loads a random PDF from the internet and displays it as a thumbnail:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. You should be able to load HTML and DOC in the UIWebView in the same way you did with PDF.

Comment: For getting thumbnail for pdf am used core graphics method.. but not found solution to get thumbnail for doc from webview

Comment: I see. I believe it should work anyway, but if not, you can maybe try this approach: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130